# Is it possible to Add in DbContext without tracking in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to do `Add`, `AddAsync`, `Update` etc in .NET Core without the entity being tracked afterwards without having to write code to specifically detach the context from tracking the entity?

```
// select, its possible to do no trackiing
var audit = _dbContext.Audit.First().AsNoTracking();

// doing an add or update, audit is now tracked unless it's detached
_dbContext.Audit.Add(audit);
int rows = _dbContext.SaveChanges();
_dbContext.Entry(audit).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

I ask this because I have a windows service that consumes `RabbitMq` messages and writes to the database. `RabbitMq` receives messages via an event handler. So the database essentially becomes a singleton even though its added as transient. I could create a new db context each time. but it seems overkill. Or is there a better way?

Comment: No, Creating a new context is not an overkill, it's prepared for that and quiet optimized. NoTracking would mean, you are sure, you don't modify the entity, nobody should oberserve it.If you add new, you definitly do modify the entity, not to track it would mean not to save it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have singleton DbContext because it is not thread safe.
You can take a look at this blog post for different approaches of managing DbContext:
https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/

Comment: thanks, yes i was adding it as transient in the windows service. my problem is that the window service listens and processes rabbit mq messages via an event handler. So what i will do instead iis when a message is received i will new up a class to process the message which will contain the dbcontext, i also need to use as part of the message processing because i need to talk to a legacy database Ingres, the predecessor of postgres. so that will be recreated also. do u see a problem wiith the latter? im mainly using it as an ado.net bridge via ODBC. should have gone with dapper but too late now